# How do I configure global Mercurial options (like extensions) in Cloudbees Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, cloudbees

I have a Cloudbees Jenkins instance configured to build several Mercurial projects.  I would like to configure global Mercurial options that would normally go in `~/.hgrc`, such as:

```
[extensions]
eol =
```

When setting up my own standalone Jenkins instance, I normally just log in as the user running Jenkins and set up its environment.

For Cloudbees, it's not clear how I should handle this.  I don't see a way to configure the Mercurial Jenkins plugin to use a specific configuration file.  Even if I could do that, I'm not sure where or when to fill in that file.

Can I somehow create a `~/.hgrc` that applies to my entire Cloudbees Jenkins instance?  Or do I need to do this on a per-job basis?  I might be able to set up `HGRCPATH` in a pre-build step via [EnvInect](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), or maybe modify the project `.hgrc` via a script build action.  However, it seems like neither of these would necessarily happen early enough in the build process to take effect when the job starts.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Can someone suggest the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the system configuration page and create a new Mercurial installation. Leave *Installation directory* blank and set *Executable* to simply `hg`, then set whatever you need in *Custom Configuration* (see the inline help). Now just select this alternate installation in your project(s).

Comment: The system configuration page on my Cloudbees Jenkins instance does not include any Mercurial section, and there's no option to select a specific Mercurial installation at the job level.  This is different than all of the standalone Jenkins instances that I maintain elsewhere.  (For reference, I'm running v1.5.4 of the Mercurial plugin.)

Comment: `https://YOURACCT.ci.cloudbees.com/configure` ought to show a section of Mercurial installations. If it does not, please file a support ticket.

Comment: Support ticket filed.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, there is now an internal dev@cloud ticket (DEV-1569) for this to be fixed, but it's apparently not on the roadmap yet.